# Report based on MV: Deliberately make the report fail if MV is out of date?

Tags: oracle, materialized-view, oracle-19c, report

I have a query that is used in a BIRT report (in IBM's Maximo Asset Management platform).

I'm considering storing the query in a materialized view in order to improve performance and reduce the load on the system.

Question:

Is a way to deliberately make the report fail  if the MV is out-of-date?

- In other words, we'd rather have **no data** in the report, than *wrong data*.

Edit:

I removed the [excessive details](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/282190/5) from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why bother at all with a new column, when you can just check `LAST_REFRESH_DATE` in `ALL_MVIEWS` before executing the actual query.

[ALL_MVIEWS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_MVIEWS.html)

And there is [basic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/basic-query-rewrite-materialized-views.html)/[advanced](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/advanced-query-rewrite-materialized-views.html) query rewrite as well.

Comment: Even with last refresh date of today the data can still be stale.

Comment: @ik_zelf Obviously. The original question was completely rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @BalazsPapp's answer:

I can check the LAST_REFRESH_DATE in ALL_MVIEWS or USER_MVIEWS:

```
select
    *
from
    wo_mv
where
    exists (select 1
            from all_mviews
            where mview_name = 'WO_MV'
                  and trunc(last_refresh_date) = trunc(sysdate) 
           )
```